# Prove that $U_{\alpha}$ is a family of unitary operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

We are in the complex Hilbert space $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ and we have a family of operators, $\alpha \in\mathbb{R} $:
$$U_{\alpha}: \{c_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\to\{e^{-in\alpha}c_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$$

1) Prove that $U_{\alpha}$ are unitary operators

2) Prove that, for $\alpha=0$ , they satisfy the property of strong continuity and the property of being an abelian group.

1) I know that in $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ the inner product between $c=\{\gamma_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $b=\{\beta_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is defined as it follows:
$$(c|b)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\overline{\gamma_k}\beta_k$$

I know that, to be an unitary operator:
$$(Uc|Ub)=(c|b)$$
So
$$(c|b)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\overline{\gamma_k}\beta_k=(Uc|Ub)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\overline{\gamma_k e^{-ik\alpha}}\beta_k e^{-ik\alpha}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\overline{\gamma_k}\beta_k e^{+ik\alpha}e^{-ik\alpha}=(c|b)$$
Right?

2) I don't know how to approach this further requirement.

Comment: In the first part of the problem, to show that $U_{\alpha}$ is a unitary operator, you also need to check that it is an isomorphism.  Not a difficult task, but there do exist non-unitary operators $U$ such that $(Uc|Ub)=(c|b)$ for all $c,b$.  I'm not quite sure what is being asked in the second part.  Are you asking if the map $\alpha\to U_\alpha$ is strongly continuous at $\alpha=0$?

Comment: I think so, the exercise's text is confusing. I don't understand what you mean with isomorphism. I know isomorphisms are bijections that go from a space $H_1$ to a space $H_2$ , $f:  H_1 \to H_2$ but I don't know how 
to proceed in this case... maybe I should prove that $U$ is both suriective and injective but right now I have no idea

Comment: Yes, I mean show that $U_\alpha$ is bijective (in addition to what you have).  Could you share the name of (or ideally a link to) the text?

Comment: It's in italian... http://wwwteor.mi.infn.it/~molinari/METODI/TEST/2017sep11.pdf

Comment: Since the exponential is never zero the the $\ker U$ should have as only element $\{0\}$ . Is it enough to prove that $U$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: You also need to show it is onto. I'll start working on an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1): from the definition of $U_\alpha$ it is obvious that $U_\alpha=\operatorname{diag}(e^{-i\alpha},e^{-2i\alpha},e^{-3i\alpha},\ldots)$ (verify that $\langle e_i,U_\alpha e_j\rangle=0\ \forall i\neq j$ so the non-diagonal matrix elements vanish; here $(e_j)_{j\in\mathbb N}$ is the standard basis of $\ell_2$). As you now have a matrix form you can just check that $U_\alpha U_\alpha^\dagger=U_\alpha^\dagger U_\alpha=\operatorname{id}_{\ell_2}$ so $U_\alpha$ is unitary as it evidently is a linear bounded operator in the first place.

2) The family of operators $(U_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\mathbb R}$ is strongly continous in $\alpha=0$ if

$$
\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\Vert (U_\alpha-U_0)x\Vert=\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\Vert (U_\alpha-\operatorname{id}_{\ell_2})x\Vert=0
$$

for all $x\in\ell_2$ where $\Vert\cdot\Vert=\sqrt{\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle}$ is the norm induced by the scalar product on $\ell_2$. Also with the explicit matrix form of the $U_\alpha$ it is easy so show that they form a group which additionally is abelian. *Hint:* it might be helpful to verify that $U_\alpha U_\beta=U_{\alpha+\beta}$ for any $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R$.

Hope this gives you the right ideas on how to proceed!

Comment: Thank you, tomorrow I'll read your answer carefully and try to solve all the exercise.

Comment: No worries, if any questions arise while solving this exercise feel free to ask back here in further comments!

Comment: If I say that $ U_{\alpha} U_{\alpha'}= e^{-in\alpha}e^{-in\alpha'}=e^{-in(\alpha+\alpha')=U_{\alpha+\alpha'}$ and that $lim_{\alpha \to 0} ||U_\alpha c_n - c_n ||=lim_{\alpha \to 0} || (e^{-in\alpha}-1)c_n ||=0$ how should I treat n? I can say that the limit above are true for any n but I'm not sure for $n \to \infty$... My idea was to show, with these two conditions, that the operator $U_\alpha$ is a strongly continuous one parameter group, wich is abelian ($I=U_0$ and $U_\alpha^{-1}=U_{-\alpha}$.

Comment: the generator of such a group should be a self-adjoint operator $H : U_\alpha = e^{-in\alpha} c_n = e^{-i\alpha H} c_n $ so I would say $H = 1$ but I'm not sure. The fact that the operator operates on a sequence confuses me! Anyway I've understood your answer, and really appreciated it. But since two days ago I've discovered new things on unitary groups and i wanted to relate them to this exercise

Comment: For $U_{\alpha} U_{\alpha'}$; since as shown before they're diagonal operators (in the standard basis), you can just treat it as a multiplication of diagonal matrices as follows: $U_{\alpha} U_{\alpha'}= (e^{-in\alpha}e^{-in\alpha'})_{n\in\mathbb N}=(e^{-in(\alpha+\alpha')})_{n\in\mathbb N}=U_{\alpha+\alpha'}$. For the strong continuity; write out the norm explicitely: $\Vert U_\alpha x-x\Vert=(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |(e^{-in\alpha}-1)x_n|^2)^{1/2}$. By the Dominated Convergence Theorem you then can interchange the sum and the limit $\alpha\to 0$ and see that  $\Vert U_\alpha x-x\Vert\to 0$.

Comment: (2/2) For the generator question: we know there exists self-adjoint $H$ on $\ell_2(\mathbb N)$ such that $U_\alpha=e^{i\alpha H}$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb R$. Here $e^{i\alpha H}$ is formally defined via the exponential series so $e^{i\alpha H}x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(i\alpha)^k H^k(x)}{k!}=U_\alpha x$ for all $x\in\ell_2$. Now you have to find an operator $H$ which satisfies that relation. (Hint: as the $U_\alpha$ are diagonal, it's reasonable to assume the same for $H$)

Comment: is $H= diag(-1, -2, -3, ...) $ ?

Comment: Yeah, I got the same result. Note that $H$ obviously is unbounded so writing $H$ as $\operatorname{diag}(-1,-2,\ldots)$ is a bit dangerous as $H$ only is defined on a dense domain (e.g. on the $\ell_2$-vectors which only have finitely many non-zero entries, else $H$ can map elements of $\ell_2$ to something which is not in $\ell_2$ anymore), c.f. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#Definitions_and_basic_properties). But this only as a side remark.

Comment: thank you, your answers are very precious! So if I write $H: \{c_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \to \{-n c_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is it ok?

Comment: Glad to help out! You have to specify the domain of $H$, namely $H:c_{00}(\mathbb N)\to\ell_2(\mathbb N)$, $(c_n)_{n=1}^\infty\mapsto (-nc_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ where $c_{00}(\mathbb N)\subset \ell_2(\mathbb N)$ is the [space of all finite sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space). Note that $c_{00}$ is dense in $\ell_2$, e.g. the $\ell_2$-norm closure of $c_{00}$ equals $\ell_2$ - so $H$ indeed is densely defined. If you don't do that, one can consider $H(1/n)_{n\in\mathbb N}=(-1,-1,\ldots)\notin\ell_2$ although $(1/n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in\ell_2$ so $H$ would not be well-defined.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you but I have a similar question , if you want to take a look it would be great : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2650224/can-i-write-mathcal-h-c-n-to-n-frac12c-n-as-h-operatorname