# Can I write $\mathcal H: \{c_n\} \to \{(n+\frac{1}{2})c_n\}$ as $H=\operatorname{diag}(\frac{1}{2}, 1 +\frac{1}{2}, 2+\frac{1}{2}, ...) $?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

We are in the Hilbert space $l^2(\mathbb{C})$ and this operator is given:
$$ \mathcal H : \{c_n\} \to \{(n+\frac{1}{2})c_n\}$$
Can I write $\mathcal H$ as $H=\operatorname{diag}(\frac{1}{2}, 1 +\frac{1}{2}, 2+\frac{1}{2}, ...) $ ?
If I can, I think that H would be:

- Invertible
- Not bounded
- Symmetric
- Self-adjoint

Is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write $H=\operatorname{diag}(\frac12,\frac32,\frac52,\ldots)$ although this only holds in a formal way. As I have also stated in the comment section of [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2645211/495075), $H:\ell_2\to\ell_2$, $(c_n)_n\mapsto ((n+\frac12)c_n)_n$ is not well-defined as it there are elements which leave $\ell_2$ when $H$ gets applied to them (e.g. $x=(\frac1n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is in $\ell_2$ but $Hx$ is not anymore as $(Hx)_n\overset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 1\neq 0$ so it's not even in $c_0$ anymore). So one way to define your operator is
$$
H:c_{00}\to\ell_2\qquad (c_n)_n\mapsto \Big(\Big(n+\frac12\Big)c_n\Big)_n.
$$
As $c_{00}$ *(space of vectors with finitely many non-zero entries)* is dense in $\ell_2$, $H$ is densely defined. Only now we can talk about properties of $H$.

- Obviously, $H$ is unbounded as $\Vert He_n\Vert=n+\frac12\overset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow \infty$ where $e_n$ is the $n$-th standard vector.
- One also quickly sees that $H$ is symmetric, just check $\langle x,Hy\rangle=\langle Hx,y\rangle$ for any $x,y\in c_{00}=D(H)$.
- $H$ as we've defined it here is *essentially self-adjoint* due to Nelson's Theorem but **not** self-adjoint for the following reason. Since $H$ is densely defined, $H^\dagger$ is closed by a well-known result. But $H$ when defined on $c_{00}$ is not closed (as can be seen easily) so $H$ and $H^\dagger$ can't coincide (basically because the domain of $H^\dagger$ is larger than the domain of $H$).
- With this definition of $H$, it is **not** invertible as it is not bijective (e.g. there is no $x\in c_{00}$ such that $Hx=(\frac1n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ so $H$ is not surjective). If you modify the target space of $H$ to be $c_{00}$, then $H:c_{00}\to c_{00}$ as defined as above is bijective with inverse
  $$
  H^{-1}:c_{00}\to c_{00}\qquad (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\mapsto \Big(\frac2{2n+1}x_n\Big)_{n\in\mathbb N}
  $$
  Writing $H^{-1}$ again in a *formal way* would yield $H^{-1}=\operatorname{diag}(2,\frac23,\frac25,\ldots)$ (but the domain of $H^{-1}$ is not all of $\ell_2$).

However, if you enlarge the domain of $H$ as follows
$$
D(H):=\lbrace x\in\ell_2\,|\,Hx\in\ell_2\rbrace\supset c_{00}
$$
then $H:D(H)\to\ell_2$ is an unbounded, densely defined operator which is self-adjoint and bijective.

The point I'm trying to make here is that some of the properties you asked about heavily depend on the domain of your (densely defined) unbounded operator.

---

For more on the topic of unbounded operators I refer to ["Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics. I: Functional Analysis" (1980) by Reed & Simon](https://books.google.de/books/about/Methods_of_Modern_Mathematical_Physics_F.html?id=fXX0j4qa8G8C&redir_esc=y)  *(Section VIII)*.

Comment: Thank you, as always clear and precise! I still have to learn a lot on this topic. I'll look for some books and theory on the subject!